# The new Markdown link validator code in Visual Studio Code, where should I enable the flag "markdown.validate.enabled": true. "

Tags: validation, visual-studio-code, hyperlink, markdown

While creating markdown files using VSCode, it is mentioned that we can enable the link validator to true. Reference: ([https://vscode-westus.azurewebsites.net/docs/languages/markdown#:~:text=Link%20validation%20is%20off%20by%20default.%20To%20enable,links%20to%20headers%2C%20images%2C%20and%20other%20local%20files.](https://vscode-westus.azurewebsites.net/docs/languages/markdown#:%7E:text=Link%20validation%20is%20off%20by%20default.%20To%20enable,links%20to%20headers%2C%20images%2C%20and%20other%20local%20files.))

Where should I set this value?

Comment: In your settings.  `Ctrl+,` to open the settings and them search for `markdown validate`.

Comment: Wow. That's a super annoying key sequence. On my Windows 10 OS the result of the `Ctrl+,` key sequence varies. Sometimes it [zooms in on the open editor document](https://www.computerhope.com/tips/tip129.htm#:~:text=Microsoft%20programs%20support-,zooming,-in%20and%20out) AND then opens the `Settings` tab. Sometimes it just zooms in on the open document and adds an unwanted comma `,` to the document. Sometimes it does both.

Comment: @Mark please consider making your comment the answer.

Comment: @ScottWelker I have added an answer with various ways to open the Settings UI - but I have never had a problem with `Ctrl+,`  - sure you don't have another command set to that keybinding?  I'm on W11.

Comment: I up-voted your answer. Hopefully the original poster (OP) will accept it. No worries about the keybinding. You answered the OPs question, and mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your settings, the Gear icon/Settings or its shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or via the Command Palette: `Preferences: Open Settings (UI)`,

then search for `markdown validate`.  You will see this option:

```
Markdown > Validate: Enabled
Enable all error reporting in Markdown files.
```

The default is `disabled` so you will have to enable it.